# Advertencia [Violation] al usar navigator.geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocalización

Estoy utilizando Geolocalización desde el navegador y me muestra esta advertencia:

[image: advertencia]

Al hacer clic sobre ella me muestra el error muestra esto:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestContent' of undefined

Entiendo que puede deberse a que la información de geolocalización no ha terminado de cargarse al momento que la muestro en consola (veo que algunos atributos vienen nulos), pero ¿que podría hacer para saber cuando ya esta cargada la información de la geolocalización para luego mostrarla?

```js
function getLocation() {
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

function success(pos) {
      var crd = pos.coords;
      console.log(crd);
    };

function error(err) {
      switch(err.code){
        case 1:
        alert("Debes habilitar el acceso a la geolocalización")
        break;
        case 2:
        alert("No se ha podido obtener la geolocalización")
        break;
        case 3:
        alert("Se ha agotado el tiempo de espera")
        break;
      }
    }; 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getLocation()">Posicionar</button>
```

Comment: Resumen de tu problema y se que es eso porque me ha pasado, para poder obtener la ubicacion del usuario deben pasar tres cosas, 1 de ellas mas importantes que las otras, 1.) tu origen debe ser **seguro**, no sirve usar direcciones ip ej. `192.168.0.26` ni tampoco el protocolo `http`, en su lugar solo son validos protocolos `https`, el `localhost` (`http://localhost`) con su puerto si es necesario y el protocolo `file://`, 2.) debes asegurarte de que tu navegador tiene acceso a la ubicacion y obviamente que tienes prendida la ubicacion.

Comment: 3.) tu error principalemente dice que para poder usar la ubicacion del usuario el usuario debe haber realizado una accion en la pagina mediante sus perifericos, ya sea por ejemplo arrastrar con el click, clickear, pulsar una tecla etc, no puedes obtener la ubicacion sin que el usuario no haya realizado una `ActionPerformed` antes, te recomiendo para eso los `EventListeners`, por ejemplo en un boton con evento tipo click puede funcionar, fuera de este `NO` lo hara.

Comment: De hecho no vi bien la pregunta, efectivamente te esta devolviendo el objeto de ubicacion que necesitas, que problema experimentas entonces?

Comment: @Riven básicamente el problema es la advertencia, sé que no es algo que afecte como tal el desempeño (o eso creo), pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de evitar que aparezca, igual no sé si en algún punto podría obtener una ubicación incorrecta por lo mismo.